# Why am I receiving 'net::ERR_ABORTED 404' when trying to use custom fonts?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ftp

I am using WordPress to create my website.

I have placed my font file inside my ftp server:

[image: ftp server with font in the folder]

In my style.css file, I have declared the different font faces and how to retrieve them:

```
@font-face{

font-family: 'Rockness';
src: url('../fonts/Rockness.ttf');}
```

I then replaced specific tags to use the specified font:

```
h1, h2 {

font-family: 'Rockness' !important;}
```

However, I am receiving 'net::ERR_ABORTED' and my website is unable to change/access the new font:

[image: Inspect element errors]

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your fonts in **web.config** (`system.webServer\staticContent`).

```
<remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
<remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff"/>
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite that in my class-wp-rewrite.php:

{
<staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="font/tff" />
  </staticContent>
}

However, it didn't work.